# Convert all Images of a Type to Another Throughout the Computer Simultanously

Tags: windows-10, jpeg, extension

I just realized my computer has been saving jpeg files as jfif for some weird reason and I have no idea since when. Is it possible to change the extension of all jfif files to jpg again throughout the computer?

Thank you.

Best wishes,

Answer (score 0):

Rename Master (freeware) can do this with a simple search/replace file extension operation. Download from here: http://www.joejoesoft.com/vcms/108/